# How to create website with 100% reliability?

Tags: php, mysql, load-balancing, database-replication

I have PHP aplication with MySQL database. I want to use something to provide 100% access to website. How to do that when one server fall down another will take over whole traffic?

I was thinking about cloning serwer, add load balancer and set up master-master replication in MySQL. Is it correct? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: What if the load balancer goes down?

Comment: 100% is impossible because a switch can go out some where and no matter how many servers you have an end user won't be able to reach it.

Comment: Even Facebook and Google go down sometimes, with their billions of dollars worth of infrastructure and experts.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the question to contain the keywords 'failover', 'redundant' and 'unlimited budget'

Comment: imo, If someone decides that your website will not be available then ... What you can do is provide enough redundancy, to a sufficient level, that it will deal with 'normal failures'? However, it can and will go wrong sometimes. i.e see 'Japan and Hurricane' ;-/ The cost is a real resource limit. It needs to balanced against the cost of `down time` and `time to restore the service`? That decision is decided  by the customer.

Comment: @Slaks - A load balancer *balancer* ***balancer***?

Comment: 100% reliability is per definition impossibly, and if anybody tells you anything else, he's lying.

Answer (score 2):

This question is too broard - 100% reliability is hard/impossible.

I can't see a simpler solution - unless you use a service provider but they will only give 99% uptime guarantee. i.e. a cloud provider. There is a difference between uptime and reliability - some people will not be able to connect due to other network issues.

If you want to do it yourself it is pretty much as your descibed, you will need a reverse proxy somewhere as well.

Also like the other comments have stated - do you mean failover etc. and you can't make it work 100% in all countries some have big firewalls ;)

Sorry I would of commented but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Now you have rep :).  I agree, although the load balancer may need to account for the databases being out of sync esp if a server has been unavailable and replication is behind the current master. The importance of that depends on the use case.

Comment: The questions too broad! But your right as well - needs a bit more detail and an idea of budget. Also reliability, access, and uptime are all seperate issues. And have no idea if its a heavy read or write database. Thanks for the Rep, been a long time lerker :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Topic is too broad. My scenario last week was:

Comment: My server was unavailable through the Internet (problem with internet provider on e24cloud in one location) but I was still able to clone server and put it on another location on e24cloud. So I do so but I had to wait for DNS propagation to everybody start see the website (another IP, same domain). Is there any way to do this faster than in 24 hours? Use load balancer? Revers proxy? Maybe you can recommend me good tutorial to this?

Comment: Was it the DNS that could not be resolved on the network? If so look at using more than 1, maybye look at cloudflare.com - I think its free - so an easy starting point. Changing the IP is not ideal but you can forward one to another.